# How to chain a custom function to express-validator?

Tags: express, express-validator

I am using [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) and I have chained some validations to `link` parameter like this:

```
route.post('/landing-pages/:link/blocks',
[
    param('link').trim().escape().isString()
],
controller.addBlocks);
```

I need to add some chained functions like `trim` and `escape` to be able to modify the value.

I can use `custom` method like the following to add new validation:

```
route.post('/landing-pages/:link/blocks',
[
    param('link').trim().escape().isString().custom((value, { req, location, path }) => 
    {
            //return true/false based on custom validation.
    }
],
controller.addBlocks);
```

But instead of validating and returning **true**/**false**, I want to modify value and change it's original source exactly the way that `trim` or `escape` is doing it. for example, I want to replace some characters or I want to remove some words, etc.

Is there anyway to do it with express-validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can chain customSanitizer function for that purpose

```
param('link').trim().escape().isString().customSanitizer(value => {
    // imagine we have a sanitizer function
    const sanitizedLink = linkSanitizer(value)
    return sanitizedLink;
  })
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't know about customSanitizer